# why does realloc crash my program when i am trying to allocate new memory?

Tags: c, function, realloc

I have some issue with my realloc function.
I have the struct Country and inside I have struct "City" which include point to cities array that every city is have 3 fields:

```
typedef struct Country {
    char *name;
    int numberOfCities;
    City* cities;
    cordinate cordinateOfCountryLeft;
    cordinate cordinateOfCountryRight;
}Country;

typedef struct City
{
    char *name;
    char * popluarFood;
    int numberOfPeople;

}City;
```

I need to delete city from the cities array so I free the city with function that I built called freeCity:

```
void freeCity(City *pCity)
{
    free(pCity->name);
    free(pCity->popluarFood);
    free(pCity);
}
```

but after delete when I am trying to realloc I get error in this function when realloc

```
status freeCityFromCountry(Country *country, char *cityName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < country->numberOfCities; i++) {//for
        if (strcmp(country->cities[i].name, cityName)==0)
        {
           freeCity(country->cities+i);
            country->cities[i] = country->cities[country->numberOfCities - 1];
          //  free(country->cities[country->numberOfCities - 1]);
            country->cities = (City*)realloc(country->cities,(country->numberOfCities-1));
            country->numberOfCities--;
            return success;
        }
    }//for
    return failure;
}
```

I malloc country->cities in other function.
Where can the problem be?

Comment: You cannot call `free` on a pointer to the middle of an allocated chunk. If you have `malloc(country->cities)`, you can only have `free(country->cities)`. The code crashes because the first call to `freeCity` frees `country->cities`. Perhaps you want `.cities` to be an array of pointers, i.e. `City**`.

Comment: @Groo, post as answer for upvote.

Comment: First allocate the memory using malloc() and if you want to allocate the more memory if the size is not enough then you do realloac() this will give extra space with the size you requested and then use free() to release the allocated memory. Don’t free the memory before realloc().

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call `free` on a pointer to the middle of an allocated chunk. `country->cities` points to a contiguous block in memory (`N x sizeof(City)`). A good rule of thumb is, if you have `malloc(something)`, you must have (and can *only* have) `free(something)` somewhere else (`malloc(country->cities)` -> `free(country->cities)`).

The code crashes because the first call to `freeCity` frees `country->cities`. Perhaps you want `.cities` to be an array of pointers, i.e. `City**`, in that case you would allocate each `City` separately, and the `cities` array would then point to chunks which you can free individually.

Comment: @DavidZaltsman: you don't need to free individual cells, because you haven't allocated them (you don't have `malloc(sizeof(City)` in your program). Removing the last line (`free(pCity)`) inside `freeCity` would resolve your issue, if you don't want to allocate individual cities. Also, a refactoring suggestion would be to split the function into `find_city_index_by_name` and `remove_city_at_index`, since you will likely search the list at several places in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you allocate `country->cities` in another function.

You are calling `freeCity(country->cities+i);`

But in the `freeCity` function you are also freeing the city `free(pCity);`

So, for the `cities` array, you are calling free on `city[i]`. This has two issues

1. For the first loop, when `i` is `0`, you are freeing the array and then reallocating it.
2. For the other iterations, when `i` is non zero, you are freeing at the wrong place. You should free the base of the array and not inside the array.

Comment: When i is 0, you are freeing `country->cities` and then reallocating `country->cities`. This is what is crashing the program

Comment: So I don't understand. If I want to free the "city" in the first cell and reduce the size of array. How can it without crash my program/?

Comment: David, you have to move all higher entries one entry down. Use `memmove`. Then use `realloc` to decrease the size.

Comment: memmove use to move string , my goal is to move the last index cell of cities that in there is 'City' object to the first cell and than free the last cell and do realloc, its going to work?